# Protractor Returning Promise Instead of Attribute Value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am trying to get the value of an html attribute and assign it to the url_extension variable using the code below but I keep getting a Promise object instead. Here is my code: (Note: wd = browser.driver;

```
   ReturnNewArticleURL : function() {
      var url_extension = this.getArticleExtension();
      console.log("url_extension: ", url_extension);
      wd.get("http://any_website.com" + url_extension) 
      return url_extension;
},

    getArticleExtension : function() {
return wd.findElement( by.id ("confirm-unpublish-url")).getAttribute("value").then(function (text) {
  return text});
},
```

If I change "return text" to console.log(text) in the getArticleExtension module then it will print the correct value for the url extension in my console. My problem is basically getting the text value outside of the .then() function and using it elsewhere. Anyone know how to do this or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rereading and thinking about @alecxe's answer I was able to figure out what I needed to do. Apparently I can only access the value of my attribute inside of the .then() function. For anyone else trying to wrap their head around this, here is how I got my code to work:

```
 ReturnNewArticleURL : function() {
    var url_extension = this.getArticleExtension();
    console.log("url_extension: ", url_extension); //prints promise as expected
    url_extension.then(function (text) {wd.get("http://any_website.com"+ text ); 
}), //this is how you use the url extension from the url_extension promise.

 getArticleExtension : function() {
      return wd.findElement( by.id ("confirm-unpublish-
       url")).getAttribute("value")
},
```

The key was using the promise value inside of the .then() function as opposed to assigning it to a variable outside.

```
url_extension.then(function (text) {
wd.get("http://any_website.com"+ text ); 
}),
```

Since protractor uses node.js it reads code asynchronously so when I assigned values to a variable that weren't evaluated at the beginning they were assigned a promise.

Comment: This is exactly what I meant, apologies for not expressing the idea in a clearer way and thanks for summarizing what helped you to solve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

`.getAttribute()` as other Protractor/WebDriverJS methods returns a [*promise*](http://www.protractortest.org/#/control-flow#promises-and-the-control-flow).

The idea is to let your function return a promise and resolve when you need an actual value:

```
ReturnNewArticleURL : function() {
    this.getArticleExtension().then(function (url_extension) {
        console.log("url_extension: ", url_extension);
    }
},

getArticleExtension : function() {
    return wd.findElement(by.id("confirm-unpublish-url")).getAttribute("value");
},
```

Comment: This only returns the correct extension in the console log which is as far as i've gotten myself. What I'm ultimately trying to do is 
wd.get(www.any_url.com + url_extension ) however this just gives me ":ManagedPromise..." instead of the extension. I'm trying to use the extension value instead ManagedPromise but can't seem to do that. I've modified my question to better reflect that.